# Remove part of programmatically created TreeView Nodes (from an XML)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have code to read a pre-definded XML file (that I can't change the content of), look for the value title and display that as a child node within a treeview.

That part is working fine, but unfortunately the XML I have to work with has unwanted text in these titles.

The results at the moment are:
https://i.gyazo.com/3bc42cae37037030a8e18b96ce59da23.png

I now need to remove the contents within the `{}` at the start of each name. I'm aware of `string.remove` etc. but given the code handles these as local vaiables I'm not sure how to handle this.

The contents in `{}` can't be predicted and can vary in length, all I can confirm for sure is that these will always be at the start.

The code I have so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BuildTree(treeView, XDocument.Load(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Mount & Blade II Bannerlord\Modules\SandBox\ModuleData\spkingdoms.xml"));
    }

    private void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, XDocument doc)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeNode = new TreeViewItem
        {
            //Should be Root
            Header = "Kingdoms",
            IsExpanded = true
        };
          treeView.Items.Add(treeNode);
          BuildNodes(treeNode, doc.Root);
    }

    private void BuildNodes(TreeViewItem treeNode, XElement element)
    {
            foreach (XNode child in element.Nodes())
            {
                switch (child.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        XElement childElement = child as XElement;
                        if (childElement.Attributes().Any(s => s.Name == "title")) { 
                            TreeViewItem childTreeNode = new TreeViewItem
                            {
                                //Get First attribute where it is equal to value
                                Header = childElement.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "title").Value,
                                //Automatically expand elements
                                IsExpanded = true
                            };
                        treeNode.Items.Add(childTreeNode);
                        BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
                    }

                        

                        break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        XText childText = child as XText;
                        treeNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = childText.Value, });
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is in `.Value` then you take it out there, perhaps by:

```
.Value.Split('}').Last()
```

You'll need a reference to System.Linq

If value is ever null, you could add a question mark between `Value` and `.`

Comment: Cool, didn't know .Split was a thing for values thanks.